# Using save method's kwargs to create another object

Tags: django

My models structure is composed by 2 models, Counts and AccessRecords. Every AccessRecord is linked to one Count and one User.

In one of my current views i usually create the Count object and then the AccessRecord.
Like this:

```
count = CountAddForm(request.POST).save()
AccessRecord.objects.create(user = request.user, count = count)
```

This works, but i might need to save Counts again in other views and i would rather have the AccessRecord creation bound to the save method.

```
count.save(**{'request_user':request.user})
```

And re-cofiguring the save method to create the AccessRecord:

```
class Count(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name = 'counts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    time_spent = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    stamped_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.start_time and self.end_time:
            self.time_spent = date(self.end_time) - date(self.start_time)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.accesses.count() == 0:
            if (not self.start_time):
                self.stamped_date = timezone.now()
            AccessRecord.objects.create(user = kwargs['request_user'], count = self)

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name = 'accesses', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    count = models.ForeignKey(Count, related_name = 'accesses', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

However this gives me an `KeyError: 'request_user'` at the line
`AccessRecord.objects.create(user = kwargs['request_user'], count = self)`

I don't understand why is this happening because my kwargs are correct.

Edit.
Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/counts/CBS%20Support/insert/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts',
 'counts',
 'django_filters',
 'site_admin',
 'invoicing_ch']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TEX368\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\TEX368\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\TEX368\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TEX368\Desktop\Django_Tutorial\bollore\bollore\decorators.py", line 8, in wrapper_func
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TEX368\Desktop\Django_Tutorial\bollore\bollore\decorators.py", line 20, in wrapper_func
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TEX368\Desktop\Django_Tutorial\bollore\counts\views.py", line 42, in InsertCounts
    count.save(**{'request_user':request.user})
  File "C:\Users\TEX368\Desktop\Django_Tutorial\bollore\counts\models.py", line 110, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /counts/CBS Support/insert/
Exception Value: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_user'
```

@Jeffrey:

```
@authenticated_user
@department_auth
def InsertCounts(request, *args, **kwargs):
        departmentTasks = Task.objects.filter(department = Department.objects.get(name = kwargs['department']))

        favoriteTasks = sorted(departmentTasks, key = lambda x: x.quantity(), reverse = True)[:10]
        tasks = tasksToDict(departmentTasks)

        context = {'department':kwargs['department'], 'taskForm':TaskSelectForm, 'countForm':CountAddForm,
        'favorite':favoriteTasks, 'tasks': tasks}

        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                task = Task.objects.get(id = request.POST['task_id'])
            except Task.DoesNotExist:
                messages.error(request, 'This task does not exist.')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('counts:insertPage', kwargs = kwargs))
            else:
                countForm = CountAddForm(request.POST)
                count = countForm.save(commit = False)
                count.task = task
                count.save(**{'request_user':request.user})

                if not sendExtraInfo(count, request.POST):
                    count.delete()
                # else:
                #     AccessRecord.objects.create(user = request.user, count = count)

                messages.success(request, 'Count successfully inserted')
        
        return render(request, r'counts\counts_insert.html', context=context)
```

Comment: can you  include full traceback of the error you're receiving.

Comment: @VishalSingh sure! Edited in the post

Comment: Looking at your Traceback, your `count.save()` didn't pass in any kwargs isn't it?

Comment: @Jeffrey sorry the traceback is now correct. I had previously changed some things in order to mantain the server running while waiting for an answer.     I did pass kwargs on the save method. The traceback is now correct

Comment: could you add the view class and function (at least where you have called the save, in your second block of code) completely?

Comment: @Jeffrey, added in the end of the post

Comment: Now this makes a lot more sense. You're **NOT** getting the KeyError, but the TypeError that is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general using kwargs to consume a keyword argument that only your method knows about, is an antipattern. It isn't clear and IDE's cannot autocomplete you. In addition, you need to handle your argument using kwargs.pop() because otherwise you end up passing it to your parent class, via the super() method, that has no clue what do with it and so you run into the TypeError that you are seeing.

A better pattern is this:

```py
class Count(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name = 'counts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    time_spent = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    stamped_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)

    def save(self, request_user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        if self.accesses.count() == 0:
            if (not self.start_time):
                self.stamped_date = timezone.now()
            AccessRecord.objects.create(user = request_user, count = self)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In fact, if you require that request_user is passed to save() always, you should use this method signature:
`def save(self, request_user, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: Thank you very much! I was mixing two different tracebacks because i went with an alternative solution while waiting for the answer and kind of forgot how it was before.. Very sorry about that.
Your sugestion about the save method is perfect

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs your model does not have a field called `request_user`.

This could be a good fix:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.start_time and self.end_time:
        self.time_spent = date(self.end_time) - date(self.start_time)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.accesses.count() == 0:
        if (not self.start_time):
            self.stamped_date = timezone.now()
        if "request_user" in kwargs: # make a check here
            request_user = kwargs.pop('request_user') # must pop
        AccessRecord.objects.create(user = request_user, count = self)
```

Comment: The other answer is another working alternation too